# Nohup command cause an error

Tags: daemon, nohup

I follow some tutorial about queuing on laravel and run it on the background, with this command

```
sudo nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=3
```

After awhile, i want to update my code, with command

```
git add .
```

but i got this error

```
error: open("nohup.out"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file nohup.out
fatal: adding files failed
```

I assume it comes from above command.
How can i solve this?

thanks man, really confused now!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late,
Can you see that file to include? I say if you use:
git status
Then if you cant, try with chmod 777 to give all permissions.